# How do I read and use /sys/kernel/mm/page_idle/bitmap?

Tags: python, c++, linux, binaryfiles

The [documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/idle_page_tracking.txt) is clear:

> The bitmap is represented by an array of 8-byte integers, and the page at PFN #i is mapped to bit #i%64 of array element #i/64, byte order is native. When a bit is
> set, the corresponding page is idle.

But I'm not experienced in linux internals, or even processing binary files. Is PFN supposed to be an integer?

What I'm trying to do is to figure out if the idle bit is set for a range of virtual addresses. I look up the virtual address range in  `/proc/{pid}/maps`, for example, `01ac3000`-`01fe5000`. How do I get the PFNs for that range and how do I read that file (in C++ or Python) to look up the idle bit?

I saw a Python example by the author of that file [here](https://lkml.org/lkml/2015/7/11/119). But I'm stuck on translating the reads that operate on the old kpageidle (which was 64 bits per page) to the bitmap file which is a compact representation.

Answer (score 2):

I think you missed one file of /proc/{pid}/pagemap, which provides the mapping of virtual address to PFN. By reading /proc/{pid}/pagemap, you can get PFN, then check the bitmap in /sys/kernel/mm/page_idle/bitmap to find out if the PFN is idle or not.